# First click on the screen changes camera position and angle at the object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

In the given script the camera is set in a certain position at the start of the game. To adjust the view, I must use mouse-drag. However, the first click on the screen the camera position and angle slightly changes.

```
public class CameraOrbit : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera cam;
    public Transform target;
    public float radius = 10;
    private Vector3 currentPosition;

    public Vector3 positionPreOffset;
    public Vector3 rotationPreOffset;

    private void Start()
    {
        // Calculate the initial camera position based on target, position offset, and rotation offset.
        Vector3 desiredPosition = target.position + target.rotation * positionPreOffset;
        cam.transform.position = desiredPosition;

        Quaternion desiredRotation = target.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(rotationPreOffset);
        cam.transform.rotation = desiredRotation;

        // Store the current camera position and calculate the radius.
        currentPosition = cam.transform.position;
        radius = currentPosition.magnitude;
    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            // Store the current mouse position when the left mouse button is clicked.
            currentPosition = cam.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        }
        else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            // Calculate the new mouse position.
            Vector3 newPosition = cam.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition);

            // Calculate the direction of mouse movement.
            Vector3 direction = currentPosition - newPosition;

            // Calculate rotation angles based on mouse movement.
            float rotationYAxis = -direction.x * 90;
            float rotationXAxis = direction.y * 90;

            // Reset the camera's position to the target's position.
            cam.transform.position = target.transform.position;

            // Apply the calculated rotations to the camera's rotation.
            cam.transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(rotXaxis, rotYaxis, 0);
            cam.transform.Translate (new Vector3(0, 0, -radius));

            currentPosition = newPosition;
        }
```

I would like if camera's position wouldn't change at the first mouse click on the screen and maintain its position and angle before I'm adjusting/changing view.

Comment: maybe add a slight delay before the movement kicks in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You completely ignore the previous applied `positionPreOffset` and `rotationPreOffset`.

Why don't you simply use [`Transform.RotateAround`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html):

```
private void LateUpdate()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        // Store the current mouse position when the left mouse button is clicked.
        currentPosition = cam.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    }
    else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        // Calculate the new mouse position.
        var newPosition = cam.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition);

        // Calculate the direction of mouse movement.
        var direction = currentPosition - newPosition;

        // Calculate rotation angles based on mouse movement.
        var rotationYAxis = -direction.x * 90;
        var rotationXAxis = direction.y * 90;

        cam.transform.RotateAround(target.position, Vector3.up, rotationYAxis);
        cam.transform.RotateAround(target.position, cam.transform.right, rotationXAxis);

        currentPosition = newPosition;
    }
}
```

which btw also fixes your issue with doing both rotations in local space while this now correctly rotates on the global Y axis

For the typical orbit camera next steps will be:

- track and clamp X rotation so you can not exceed `+/- 90°` or even less depending on your use case

  For this you can simply sum up the value of `rotationXAxis` and then only actually execute the rotation using an amount that does not exceed the allowed range
- add zoom

  Quite trivial: Simply move the camera towards or away from the pivot point.
- clamp zoom

  As before you keep track of your current distance to the pivot and limit our zoom to respect the limitations